# How to save updated data in database in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions

I have installed [kartik Yii 2 Editable extension](http://demos.krajee.com/editable) make columns editable.

Working fine but the updated data does not store in databse.how to store it in database ?

**index.php**

```
  [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
                'editableOptions' => [
                    'header' => 'status',
                    'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
                    'type' => 'danger',
                    'placement' => 'right',
                    'options' => [
                        'pluginOptions' => ['min' => 0, 'max' => 5000]
                    ]
                ],
                'attribute' => 'status',
                'hAlign' => 'center',
                'label' => 'Status',
                'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter' => [ 'Present' => 'Present', 'Absent' => 'Absent', 'Leave' => 'Leave',],
                'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'search by status'],
                'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
                ],
            ],
```

**controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new AttendanceSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        if(isset($_POST['hasEditable'])){
            $staffindex=$_POST['editableIndex'];
            $status = $_POST['Attendance'][$staffindex]['status'];
            $staffid=$_POST['editableKey'];
            //save attendence
            return true;
        }
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: any `update()` method?

Comment: @Insane Skulll  thanx its work.